# How Mozilla addon's nsiObserver works?

Tags: firefox-addon

I was trying to make an extension to observe custom URI stamp. So I need help to know how it can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every observer expects an object that contains a function called `observe` which receives 3 arguments like this:

```
var blasfasf = {
observe: function(some_subject, some_topic, some_data) {
// responder
console.log('im responding to:', some_topic, 'and data coming with it is:', 'some_subject:', some_subject, 'some_data:', some_data);
}
}
```

now this is the responder. whenever an observe fires on `some_topic` it will fire this observer if you added it with

```
Services.ob.addObserver
```

To add the above to say time http-on-modify-request you would go like this:

```
Services.ob.addObserver('http-on-modify-request', blasfasf, false);
```

third arg is false, unless you want weak reference, i never found a use for it but it desrves research can help avoid zombie compartments

Now anytime a browser fires http-on-modify-request it will trigger your observer

Now you can also make your own some_topic add this to your own observer.

Lets add this to `my_stamped`.

So we do just do this:

```
Services.ob.addObserver('my_stamped', blasfasf, false);
```

and then to trigger our observer we go:

```
var subject_to_send = 'my made up subject';
var data_to_send = 'my made up data';
Services.ob.notifyObserver(subject_to_send, 'my_stamped', data_to_send);
```

and that will trigger your observer callback.